# what are the consequences of using ${-0}$ in exponentiation?

Tags: exponentiation

mainly in regards to $10^{-0}$, $-10^{-0}$, $0^{-0}$, $-0^0$ and $-0^{-0}$

i have have tried wolframalpha but i can't get it to interpret ${-0}$ as ${-0}$, it just interprets it as ${0}$

Comment: $-0$ **is** $0$. What else would it be?

Comment: If $-0$ is not $0$ then $0-0$ is not $0$ either.

Comment: I concur with Gerry Myerson. In any algebraic structure, the symbol $-x$ denotes the additive inverse of $x$, and $0$ is the additive identity. The additive inverse of $0$ is $0$, since $0+0=0$, since $0$ is the additive identity. Thus $-0=0$. This is just how it is. It is incoherent to treat $0$ as the additive identity and then say $-0\neq0$.

Comment: This being said, some people write $f(0^-)$ when they really mean $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0, \varepsilon > 0} f(\varepsilon)$

Comment: but doesn't the signage affect the outcome?, making say $10^{-0}={-1}$?, that is what im asking.

Comment: Where do you see these notations? Meanings of notations may depend on contexts.

Comment: Are you talking about the [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)?

Comment: What on Earth makes you think $10^{-0}=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the reason Wolfram Alpha interprets $-0$ as $0$ is because $-0$ *is* $0$. They are one and the same.

$0$ is the identity element of addition: the number such that for any other number $a$, $a + 0 = 0$. There can be only one identity element. Because if $e$ also has this property, then $e + 0 = 0$ by $0$ being an identity, and $e + 0 = e$ by $e$ being an identity. So $e = e + 0 = 0$. They are the same number.

For any number $a$, the number $-a$ is by definition the number such that $a + (-a) = 0$. Again, for a given $a$, there is can be only one such number. For if $a + b = 0$ and $a + c = 0$, then $$c = 0 + c =(b + a) + c = b + (a + c) = b + 0 = b$$So every number has a unique opposite.

But $0 + 0 = 0$, which means that $0$ is the unique number which when added to $0$ results in $0$. By the definition of "$-a$" given above, that means, $-0 = 0$. They are the exact same number.

So

- $10^{-0} = 10^0 = 1$.
- $-10^{-0} = -(10^{-0}) = -(1) = - 1$, because exponentiation has precedence over negation as operators.
- $(-10)^{-0} = (-10)^0 = 1$ because any real number raised to the power of $0$ is $1$ (Okay, some people have a snit about defining $0^0 = 1$, since $0^x = 0$ for all $x > 0$. But I won't get into why they are so, so wrong about that here.)
- $0^{-0} = 0^0 = 1$
- $(-0)^0 = 0^0 = 1$
- $(-0)^{-0} = 0^0 = 1$